# NO autofocus field, still my page scrolls down when the iframe changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have a side navigation bar, when i click on any link, a specific iframe content is loaded in the right space.
Now, there is just one page that has a an input form in it. That iframe on loading is working completely fine(not scrolling to bottom) but the other iframes where there is no input tag, are scrolling downwards. And focusing on the footer(where no input field is present as well)
Any clue what the underlying issue might be?

Edit:
here's the code structure

Html of the main page.

```
<div class="main-container">
        <div
          class="sidenav">
       
          <ul style="padding: 0">
            <a id="xyz"  href="#xyz">
              <img src="xyz.svg" />
              XYZ</a
            >

            <a id="abc" href="#abc">
              <img src="abc.svg" />
              ABC</a
            >
           </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- side nav end  -->

        <div class="container-fluid side-content">

          <iframe src="xyz.html" id="xyz-frame" height="100%" width="100%" style="outline: none; border:none; "></iframe>

          <iframe src="abc.html" id="abc-frame" height="100%" width="100%" style="outline: none; border:none; "></iframe>

        

        <!-- Side content end -->
        </div>

      </div>

    <footer>
      <!--footer content--!>
    </footer>
```

CSS main:

```
#xyz-frame,#abc-frame{
display:none;
}
```

JS main:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#xyz").click(function() {
    $("iframe").hide();
    $("#xyz-frame").show();
  });
});

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#abc").click(function() {
    $("iframe").hide();
    $("#abc-frame").show();
  });
});
```

xyz.html

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid side-content">
          <div class="container-fluid container-heading">
            <p class="heading">Locations</p>
          </div>


          <div class="container-fluid container-list-items">
            <div class="grid-1">
              <p style="align-self: center">123</p>
              <img style="align-self: center" src="img.svg" />
              <p style="align-self: center">celia</p>
              <p style="align-self: center">celia</p>
              <p style="align-self: center">celia</p>
              <p style="align-self: center">2020</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you put up a minimal example of code so we can take a closer look.

Comment: hey @AHaworth. Thankyou for replying I've added the code. please check it now